# Tips for making the Android launcher transparent

Tags: android

I'm designing a custom Android 4.0 (ICS) device for special purpose.

One of the things I'm looking for is a way to make the Android Launcher, when other activities were previously running, show the last running activity as a transparent, dimmed background, with the launcher icons and widgets on top.

What I'm looking for, is something like this: [How do I create a transparent Activity on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android), except as a modification to Launcher2. I guess I can apply a similar style to the launcher as proposed in that SO, but what about the wallpaper?

AFAIU, the wallpaper is rendered by a separate service, and I still want it rendered if there are no other activities behind the launcher.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this one out myself eventually. It turned out pretty simple.

Just modify the theme as suggested in the mentioned SO-article, and simply change inheritance from the Wallpaper-enabled theme.

Also, there were a small code-snippet that was reactivating the wallpaper. Switch that out, and I've now got a transparent launcher, that shows what's going on behind it.